# Installer for Windows 8.1 App outside Windows Store

Tags: powershell, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

I have a universal windows application for windows 8.1 and windows phone (WAP)
But my customer doesn't have access to the windows store, there's a way to use Installshield or something similar to generate a Setup Installer?

At the moment i have to type some code in powershell and it's really annoying and unprofessional.

There's a workaround for this situation?

Comment: First of all - UWP does not run on W8.1. You probably mean Universal Application for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. If it's UWP you may create a package where the APPX works as an installer. Other way you could also create for example a WPF app to invoke the PowerShell script. But maybe there're some better ways to approach what you need.

Comment: Marian, yes it's a universal application for windows 8,1 and windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

The Suite/Advanced UI project type (Premier edition of recent enough versions—probably 2012 Spring) has support for [side-loading .appx packages](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/SteAppXPackages.htm). More recent versions (2016 or so) add support for Windows 10 UWP App Packages.